# Append anchor tag inside list-item

Tags: jquery, append, each

I have an unordered list:

Html:

```
<ul id="blogs">
   <li>
     <a class="vimg" href="/blogs/news/6875583-hurricane-sandy">
      <img src="mydomainvideo_icons.jpg?1542">
    </a>
 </li>
    <a href="/blogs/news/6875583-hurricane-sandy">
      <strong class="titlen">Hurricane Sandy</strong>
      <p class="newsp">lorem ispum lorem ispumu...</p>
    </a>
    <a class="readp" href="/blogs/news/hurricane-sandy">Read More</a>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to alter the html above with jQuery, so the output would be the following:

```
  <ul id="blogs">
   <li>
      <a class="vimg" href="/blogs/news/6875583-hurricane-sandy">
       <img src="mydomainvideo_icons.jpg?1542">
     </a>
     <a href="/blogs/news/6875583-hurricane-sandy">
       <strong class="titlen">Hurricane Sandy</strong>
       <p class="newsp">lorem ispum lorem ispumu...</p>
    </a>
    <a class="readp" href="/blogs/news/hurricane-sandy">Read More</a>
 </li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
```

This is the jquery I have but its a not working:

jQuery:

```
  $("#blogs li").each(function(){

       if ($(".video-container").length > 0  && $(this).children('img').length == 0){
          var vidindex = $('.readp').attr('href')
          $(this).find('.video-container').remove();
          $(this).append('<a class="vimg" href=""><img src="{{ 'video_icons.jpg' | asset_url }}"/></a>');
          $('.titlen').appendTo('.vimg')
          $(this).find('a').attr("href", vidindex)
     }
      $(this).find('img').replaceWith(function(){ return '<img src="'+this.src+'"/>';});
});
```

Comment: does the code fails altogether? does it throw any error? does it produce the output but not the desired one? saying it doesnt work doesnt help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Append anchor tag inside list-item

```
$("#blogs").find("li").append("<a href='#'>some Description</a>");
```

Comment: i think the OP is also using `.append` with a different approach, the problem seems to be in the template code he is trying to put in the `src` attribute in `.append`

Comment: ohh I didn't see that, looks to me he is using mustache and thats causing the error.

Comment: If you want to append to only the first instance of `li`, then it's `find("li").first().append..`