# jQuery Adding <a href="#"

Tags: jquery

I have the following snippet that currently returns `<li>`.  How can I make it return `<li><a href="#"`  I am not going to be using the `href` but I am using Boostrap3 so I need it for the Navigation.

**Code:**

```
  fetchJSON.done(function(response) {
        var buttons = response.map(function(i) {
            return $('<li>', {
                text: i.title,
                "data-author": i.author,
                "data-body": i.body
            })
        });
        $('ul').append(buttons);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As easily as

```
        return $('<li>', {
            "data-author": i.author,
            "data-body": i.body
        }).append($('<a>', { href: '#', text: i.title }))
```

I would also recommend you using:

```
.data({
    author: i.author,
    body: i.body
})
```

instead of crafting them manually

Answer (score 0):

you must be able to directly use the append method

```
.append("<a href='#'>some Description</a>");



return $('<li>', {
            text: i.title,
            "data-author": i.author,
            "data-body": i.body
        }).append("<a href='#'>some Description</a>");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of the below question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355755/append-anchor-tag-inside-list-item